# map_msgs/GetMapROI

Tags: ros, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what does ROI mean? Can someone link me to something that points out how this is used? I see it has an OccupancyGrid in it. I'm looking for a little direction. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127221/map_msgs/getmaproi/) by [david.c.liebman](https://answers.ros.org/users/9071/david.c.liebman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2014-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess would be: Get Map Region Of Interest.
It should be used to get a partial map in the specified coordinates.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0